# how to pass parameter as key and other parameters as body in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I need to pass act, email,userid in body and session_id in key. I am using Postman and I am getting the desired result. But I am not able to do it in Objective C. I am using AFNetworking

**This is what I am trying to achieve.**
[image]

```
-(void)CallUpdateAPI
{

    AFHTTPSessionManager *apicall = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    apicall.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    NSMutableDictionary *parameters2 =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
   [parameters2 setObject:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userlist"] objectForKey :@"userid"] forKey:@"userid"];

    NSNumber *v1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

   [parameters2 setValue:v1 forKey:@"act"];

   [parameters2 setObject:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userlist"] objectForKey :@"session_id"] forKey:@"session_id"];
   [parameters2 setObject:_email.text forKey:@"email"];
    NSLog(@"Server response : %@ ",parameters2);


   [apicall POST:@"https://portal.blockage.io/api/v1/user/kyc_update" parameters:parameters2  progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)
   {
        NSError *e = nil;
        NSMutableDictionary *resultFromPost2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseObject options: 0 error: &e];
        //NSLog(@"Server response : %@ %@",resultFromPost2,e);
        //... 
   }
     //... 
}
```

Comment: `session_id` seems to be in Headers, not in Body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your session_id parameter is a "Get" parameter. You need to set it in the url not in the body.

```
"https://portal.blockage.io/api/v1/user/kyc_update?session_id=YourSessionID"
```

You can use this:

```
NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://portal.blockage.io/api/v1/user/kyc_update?session_id=%@", [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userlist"] objectForKey :@"session_id"];
[apicall POST:urlString parameters:parameters2  progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a dictionary with the suitable body params:

```
 NSDictionary *bodyPArams = @{@"xxx":@"xxx",
                              @"xxx":@"xxx",
                              @"xxx":@"xxx",
                              @"xxx":@"xxx"};
```

and call the POST method:

```
[apicall POST:@"https://portal.blockage.io/api/v1/user/kyc_update" parameters:bodyPArams progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

}];
```